# Easy way to find if an array is 2d array or not?

Tags: ruby

There has be a better alternative to find if array is 2d array.

```
my_array = [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"]]
!my_array.map{|element| element.is_a? Array}.include? false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a concept of `2D` or `nD` arrays. Please define it. I assume all elements of `array` are arrays, but are they necessary all equal in size, as would be the case for a 2D matrix?

Answer (score 7):

I've assumed that by "2d array" (which has no meaning in Ruby), the OP wants to determine if every element of the array is an array and all those element arrays are the same size, as is the case with a "2d matrix".

**Edit 2:** Here's another way (much better than my original answer below!):

```
def all_elements_arrays_of_same_size?(a)
  !!(a.transpose rescue nil)
end

all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"]]
  #=> true 
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],["c", "d", "g"],["e", "f"]]
  #=> false 
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],"c",["e", "f"]]
  #=> false
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],"c", {a:1}]
  #=> false
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 1]
  #=> false
```

**Edit 1:** @WandMaker makes a very good point [regarding my original answer below]. Formerly I had `a.map(&:size).minmax.uniq.size`. Ive removed `minimax` as he suggested.]

I assumed a "2D array" is an array whose elements are arrays of the same size.

```
def all_elements_arrays_of_same_size?(a)
  a.all? { |e| e.class==Array } && a.map(&:size).uniq.size == 1
end

all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"]]
  #=> true 
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],["c", "d", "g"],["e", "f"]]
  #=> false 
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],"c",["e", "f"]]
  #=> false
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [["a", "b"],"c", {a:1}]
  #=> false
all_elements_arrays_of_same_size? [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 1]
  #=> false
```

For the last example, note `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].size #=> 8` and `1.size #=> 8`.

The steps are as follows:

For:

```
array = [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"]]

array.all? { |e| e.class==Array }
  #=> true 
a = array.map(&:size)
  #=> [2, 2, 2] 
b = a.uniq
  #=> [2] 
b.size == 1
  #=> true
```

On the other hand, for:

```
array = [["a", "b"],["c", "d", "g"],["e", "f"]]

array.all? { |e| e.class==Array }
  #=> true 
a = array.map(&:size)
  #=> [2, 3, 2] 
b = a.uniq
  #=> [2, 3] 
b.size == 1
  #=> false
```

For:

```
array = [["a", "b"],"c", {a:1}]

array.all? { |e| e.class==Array }
  #=> false
```

Comment: Can we use just `uniq` instead of `minmax.uniq` as I think it `minmax` does not achieve anything?

Comment: Hats off to Wand! (Wand you can [leave yours on](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fe/9d/95/fe9d953c8dc8edccde5ad7dec9bdf039.jpg).)

Answer (score 4):

Super easy!

`my_array.all? { |e| e.kind_of? Array }`

Take a look at the [enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) module. You use `all?` if you want to check all the elements and `any?` if having one element that is an array is enough. Those methods are documented in the link

Comment: I want to check if all element are array inside an array. I think all should help. Thanks.

Comment: @AnkushGanatra: In that case, `my_array.all? { |e| e.kind_of? Array }`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the clarified specification, this would work to ensure that you only have a 2D, and not 3+D array:

```
my_array.all? { |e| (e.kind_of? Array) && e.flatten(1) == e}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`all?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F):

```
a = [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"]]
#=> [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
a.all?{|el| el.is_a? Array}
#=>true
```

In Ruby, Arrays are objects, they **only have one dimension**. But they can hold anything, including other arrays, so they can behave as multi
dimensional arrays.